Why does Windows 11 display a different ethernet MAC (hardware) address than Linux?
I have a set of 1G Ethernet USB adapters. To keep them organized, I wanted to label them with MAC address so I could easily identify the correct interface when more than one was connected.
I plugged three of them into a Linux machine, and got three similar addresses:
20:23:51:92:5b:64
20:23:51:92:62:15
20:23:51:92:6c:ce

One was already plugged into a Windows system, so I did IPCONFIG /ALL and looked at the hardware (Physical) address:
E4-B9-7A-C9-7A-6D

I looked up 20:23:51 at https://macaddress.io, and it was correctly identify as TP-Link.
I looked up E4:B9:7A and the OUI is registered to Dell. The Windows system is Dell, but the USB adapter is the same TP-Link as the others above.
Out of curiosity, I moved the adapter to the Linux system and ip a told me the link/ether address for the adapter is 20:23:51:92:5b:66 which is consistent with the other adapters.
I thought maybe Windows was configured for Random MAC, but E4 is not a local address. There was no an override MAC address in the adapter settings either.
Why would Windows 11 present the physical address differently?

my first guess is that the mac address you are seeing in ipconfig /all is not the address of the USB adapter, but the one for the built in ethernet port. even if an adapter is not in use, it will still have a MAC address, and it may be that ipconfig is confused by the USB connection. just a guess.

I looked at the adapter's advanced settings in Windows and discovered "MAC Passthrough" was enabled.  I was unfamiliar with that term, so a quick search brought me to https://www.dell.com/support/kbdoc/en-us/000143263/what-is-mac-address-pass-through.

there's another reason this could happen - on wireless there's an option for  randomised mac addresses. Its clearly not the case here, but if its not a fixed connection, its worth considering

@tim11g before  "MAC Passthrough"  it was common for software licensing systems to fail when doctoring stations had a network connection as well as the ethernet port in the laptop.

It is caused by MAC Passthrough in the adapter settings. Apparently enabled by default by Dell for USB Ethernet.
For more details, see What is MAC Address Pass-through on Dell Support.

Nice catch. I was wondering if it wasn't something like that, since USB connections are software defined, leaving lots of room for the OS and third-party drivers to mess with it.

the reason Dell enables this by default is to allow corporate network to whitelist PCs but not have to individually whitelist docking stations (which is counter-productive, since then any PC can use the docking station as if it's whitelisted). I'm actually surprised they eventually did this, a few years ago this was our main gripe with them.

@Themoonisacheese Business-class laptops from most (all?) major vendors have supported MAC passthrough for ages, it just wasn't always on by default. But then in a corporate environment, firmware configuration is typically centrally managed, so does it really matter much if this is the default or just one of the many things you need to set when provisioning a new laptop?

@TooTea it's been years since i left that place but i think our main issue was that we wanted to provision laptops over the network, but they only had usb-c ports and no rj-45, so we had "blessed" usb-c to rj45 adapters that were the only ones whitelisted and it didn't feel very good.

Some 802.1x port authentication setups also require the laptop's mac address to be visible to the network switching, not a random one from a dock or USB/PCcard adapter.  This is gratuitously-corporate so right up Dell's street.

@Themoonisacheese: The DELL explanation screams "We're doing security wrong!"  The problem is using an easily-spoofed identifier for security purposes.  The correct solution would be to use a client certificate preloaded in UEFI... then the same certificate is presented regardless of network adapter, and the network adapters themselves still have distinct MAC addresses and don't collide if multiple are plugged into the same network segment.

@BenVoigt Agreed, except maybe it screams "Our customers are doing security wrong!" ;-)

The link states that the MAC pass-through (or rather, adapter MAC overwrite) happens at boot, before an OS is loaded (presumably to allow network resource access like DHCP). Does Linux then revert that?

@BenVoigt: sure, probably. I haven't worked there for several years, and i was not a decision-maker, so i couldn't do anything about it if i wanted to. i was also too junior to know better.

@Peter-ReinstateMonica: from what i can tell the EUFI program is responsible for initializing the USB device at boot, and configures itself to use MAC passthrough, but the OS loaded after it may reinit or reconfigure usb devices as it sees fit. I think linux pretty much always reinits USB devices on boot.

@Themoonisacheese MAC passthrough works on Linux just fine (unless your kernel is truly ancient). The adapter would have the same passed-through MAC on that Dell machine even if that machine ran Linux instead of Windows. The Linux/Windows distinction here is a red herring, it's just that the "Linux" machine does not have passthrough enabled and the "Windows" machine does.

@BenVoigt I didn't even know about the certificate in UEFI thing. Our machines come straight from the manufacturer with AutoPilot/Intune setup, and still don't get on the network until they have the Windows fully setup with the user - literally need to go off of guest Wi-Fi or mobile network to perform the install, it's nuts

@TooTea: i know. but even with passthrough enabled, linux (and most likely windows, i don't know) will always reinit usb devices on boot, it'll just happen to reinit the adapter into the same state it was. (this is also why setting numlock state in UEFI doesn't work with linux)

@Themoonisacheese Oh, OK, now I see what you meant. But that's true for pretty much any device (not just USB), across operating systems. All device drivers need to start by initializing the device because otherwise you can't know what state you got it in (perhaps it was just hotplugged, perhaps it's in an inconsistent state after a warm boot, perhaps the firmware already used it for something and left it in some random state). I should have probably directed my reply to Peter instead, sorry for the confusion.

@BenVoigt Getting such a certificate preloaded requires either that the vendor does it for you (I guess you have to be a really big customer for them to bother), or somebody manually setting it all up. It's much easier to just plug a brand new laptop in, see an unknown MAC pop up on the network, compare that with the MAC written on the box (or scan the provided barcode) and boom, machine is authorized, gets an address, boots off PXE and installs itself. Of course it's better to use 802.1x from that point on, but for initial provisioning the MAC is secure enough.

@BenVoigt In other words, the MAC address is not used as a secret for authentication, but as an unique identifier so that the network knows which piece of hardware it's talking to.

@TooTea: (1) It's not a unique identifier, since it can be spoofed, and the Dell feature does in fact spoof it and make it non-unique.  (2) The feature was described as enabling "MAC whitelist" which does use it as the authentication secret.  (3) If Dell is willing to preload all their business-class computers with serialized special MAC addresses not associated with any hardware, they can do the same with a client certificate.  I'm not envisioning that these would be generated by the customer's own CA, but by Dell, and not specialized to the ordering customer in any way.
